# Custom tooltip contents @ ngx-charts | Angular2+ | TypeScript

Tags: label, tooltip, ngx-charts

I've been trying to set a custom label in a line chart's tooltip , e.g., modified number of minutes in HH:mm format (74 min --> 1:14), for quite some time now, but unfortunately without any success. Displaying the value as 1.283(...3) is not an alternative.

[Number to HH:mm as tooltip label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKreK.png)

Does anybody know how to preserve the x and y axis values (a date and a number respectively), and modify the tooltip display value?

For example: https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/#/ngx-charts/line-chart

Instead of having a tooltip that displays Color, Country name and Number,
--> Color, Country name and String (Number > 3000 ? 'high' : 'low';)

**Current behavior**
Works as intended.

**Expected behavior**
To display custom labels.

**Reproduction of the problem**
Link in the description above

**What is the motivation / use case for changing the behavior?**
Being able to customize tooltips' contents

**Please tell us about your environment:**
OS: Win 10 x64, IDE: Eclipse EE

**ngx-charts version:** 3.0.2

**Angular version:** 6.0.2

**Browser:** [all]

**Language:** [TypeScript 2.3.3]

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can define your own tooltip templates and render any HTML you like in them:

```
<ngx-charts-line-chart        
    [scheme]="colorScheme"
    [results]="multi" ...>
  <ng-template #tooltipTemplate let-model="model">
    This is the single point tooltip template
    <pre>{{model|json}}</pre>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template #seriesTooltipTemplate let-model="model">
    This is vertical line tooltip template
    <pre>{{model|json}}</pre>        
  </ng-template>
</ngx-charts-line-chart>
```

Example: https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/#/ngx-charts/tooltip-templates

Code is here: https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/blob/8ebb3dbcbbea443fefdcafd1f5c9069df0e0c4ae/src/app/app.component.html#L992-L998

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've read the source code from the tooltip and line-chart components. When I try to put anything between <ng-template> </ng-template> I get the following: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: ':svg:pre' is not a known element, where pre would be the tag I tried to insert in between. Another thing is, I get "undefined" for every self defined attribute in my object except for .name and .value, which are the only ones currently available for line-chart. Here's the latest state: github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/issues/932

Comment: Here's an stackblitz where this is working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vertical-bar-chart-yvy5bx?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thank you! i was having a hard time trying to pass it as an input instead of content child.

Answer (score 3):

The above solution does not work for multi-dimensional charts ( > 3) like Stacked Horizontal/Vertical Bar.

Another simple way which works for all cases is to add the `tooltipText` as an attribute as part of the model like below:

```
export let multi = [
  {
    name: 'Germany',
    series: [
      {
        name: '2010',
        value: 7300000,
        tooltipText: 't1'
      },
      {
        name: '2011',
        value: 8940000,
        tooltipText: 't2'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Then use the following code in markup,

```
<ngx-charts-bar-horizontal-stacked
      [view]="view"
      [scheme]="colorScheme"
      [results]="multi"
      [gradient]="gradient"
      [xAxis]="showXAxis"
      [yAxis]="showYAxis"
      [legend]="showLegend"
      [legendPosition]="legendPosition"
      [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
      [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
      [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
      [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
      (select)="onSelect($event)">
  <ng-template #tooltipTemplate let-model="model">
    <div class="tooltip">
      {{model.tooltipText}}
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngx-charts-bar-horizontal-stacked>
```

Comment: Hi there, i couldn't able to see  tooltipText property in mode object.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, once again. Didn't want to leave the issue unresolved.
The problem was **the code snippet was inside a svg** element.
Here's the final version:

```
<!--  This is single point tooltip template -->
<xhtml:ng-template #tooltipTemplate let-model="model">
  <xhtml:div class="area-tooltip-container">
    <xhtml:div *ngFor="let tooltipItem of model | json | durationHhmm" class="tooltip-item" style="text-align: center;">
      <a style=" font-size: 1.2em;">{{tooltipItem.series}}</a><a *ngIf="tooltipShowTime==='DAY' || tooltipShowTime==='WEEK'" style=" font-size: 1.2em;"><br />{{tooltipItem.name | date: 'HH:mm'}} Uhr</a><a *ngIf="tooltipShowTime!=='DAY' && tooltipShowTime!=='WEEK'" style=" font-size: 1.3em; font-weight: 600;"><br />&#183;</a><br /><a style=" font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: 600;">{{tooltipItem.name | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}} &#183; </a><a style=" font-size: 1.3em; font-weight: 600;">{{tooltipItem.value}}</a>
    </xhtml:div>
  </xhtml:div>
</xhtml:ng-template>

<!-- Datapoints Y-Axis -->
<svg:g *ngFor="let series of data">
  <svg:g ngx-charts-circle-series
         [xScale]="xScale"
         [yScale]="yScale"
         [colors]="colors"
         [data]="series"
         [scaleType]="scaleType"
         [visibleValue]="hoveredVertical"
         [activeEntries]="activeEntries"
         [tooltipDisabled]="tooltipDisabled"
         [tooltipTemplate]="tooltipTemplate"
         (select)="onClick($event, series)"
         (activate)="onActivate($event)"
         (deactivate)="onDeactivate($event)"
  /> 
</svg:g>
```