# Angular NGX-Charts: using a custom legend

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

There was a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51946802/angular-ngx-charts-options-for-customizing-the-legend), but I need clarification on the answer and don't have enough rep to comment. Paging user @Maya Sol.

I am trying to recreate her answer but I have not been successful and I am wondering where I am going wrong.

```
<ngx-charts-legend 
    [data]="sizeByTypeNames" 
    [title]="'Legend Title'" 
    [colors]="colors" 
    [activeEntries]="activeEntries" 
    (labelActivate)="legendLabelActivate($event)"
    (labelDeactivate)="legendLabelDeactivate($event)">
</ngx-charts-legend>



this.colors = new ColorHelper(this.colorScheme, 'ordinal', this.sizeByTypeNames, this.colorScheme);

this.sizeByTypeNames: string[] = [an array of the names each legend label should have]
```

I don't get any errors and I can see the legend title, but there is no content within the legend.

Comment: Can you see the line chart?
Do you have any console errors?
Can you post the whole HTML file and if you can the component as well?

Comment: Solution would be appreciated

Comment: @Spikolynn I have posted the solution as an answer to this thread.

Comment: @WambuaMakenzi  I have posted the solution as an answer to this thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Component template and related functions:

```
<div>
    <ngx-charts-pie-chart
        [scheme]="colorScheme"
        [results]="chart.data"
        (select)="onSelect($event)">
    </ngx-charts-pie-chart>
</div>
<div *ngIf="legend" class="chart-legend">
    <ngx-charts-legend 
        [data]="chart.legendData"
        [colors]="chart.colors"
        (labelClick)="onLabelClick($event, chart.data)">
    </ngx-charts-legend>
</div>


onLabelClick(event: any, data: any) {
    let result = data.find((obj: any) => {
        return obj.extra.displayName === event;
    })
    this.onSelect(result);
}


onSelect(event: any) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

Example of my DataSource, where I am getting data from an API and then setting these chart properties:

```
chart: Chart =
    {
        title: 'Some Title',
        subtitle: 'A descriptive subtitle',
        data: this.chartData,
        legendData: [],
        colors: new ColorHelper('cool', 'ordinal', [], null),
        type: 'pie'
    }

chartData = [];

this.myService.getChartData(body).subscribe(
    result => {
        let data = result.data;
        for (let d in data) {
            let name = d;
            let val = data[d];
            let newDataPoint: NewDataPoint = {
                'name': name,
                'value': val,
                'extra': {
                    'displayName': name,
                    'displayValue': val
                }
            }
            this.chartData.push(newDataPoint);
        }
        chart.data = [...this.chartData];
        chart.legendData = chart.data.map(d => d['extra']['displayName']);
        chart.colors = new ColorHelper('neons', 'ordinal', chart.legendData, null);
    }
);
```